# Wifi AP with ASUS USB-N10

Tags: linux, gentoo, wifi, gnu

I am trying to configure wifi AP with subj device. According documentation in web, it requires `master mode` hardware support and `hostapd` software.

It seems I have master mode:

```
# iwconfig
...
wlp0s29u1u2  unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
      Mode:Master  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

But, when I try to start hostapd `hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, it silently exits with `$? = 1`. When I tried it on laptop, it works out of a box,
but, probably it worth noting that I had to build N10 driver(8712u) from source.

`Linux Dungeon 3.7.10-gentoo-gnu #11 SMP Sun Mar 31 23:12:28 MSK 2013 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Here is content of `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
ssid=YourWifiName
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
auth_algs=3
channel=7
hw_mode=g
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
max_num_sta=5
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Also, I found probably intresting thing in `$(dmesg)`:

```
[193240.231986] WARNING: at kernel/timer.c:1056 del_timer_sync+0x2b/0x50()
[193240.231988] Hardware name: System Product Name
[193240.231990] Modules linked in: 8712u(O)
[193240.231995] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W  O 3.7.10-gentoo-gnu #11
[193240.231998] Call Trace:
[193240.232005]  [<c103170d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x6d/0xa0
[193240.232008]  [<c104001b>] ? del_timer_sync+0x2b/0x50
[193240.232011]  [<c104001b>] ? del_timer_sync+0x2b/0x50
[193240.232015]  [<c103175d>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1d/0x20
[193240.232018]  [<c104001b>] del_timer_sync+0x2b/0x50
[193240.232032]  [<f880f460>] surveydone_event_callback+0x2e/0x130 [8712u]
[193240.232041]  [<f87ffc52>] ? fwdbg_event_callback+0x2d/0x33 [8712u]
[193240.232048]  [<f8800373>] event_handle+0xf3/0x107 [8712u]
[193240.232063]  [<f88198e5>] rxcmd_event_hdl+0x21/0x31 [8712u]
[193240.232068]  [<f88047d4>] usb_read_port_complete+0x84/0x182 [8712u]
[193240.232071]  [<c147d626>] usb_hcd_giveback_urb+0x36/0x90
[193240.232073]  [<c148cb14>] ehci_urb_done+0x64/0xa0
[193240.232076]  [<c148ef7a>] qh_completions+0x26a/0x500
[193240.232078]  [<c1054b31>] ? hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x21/0x30
[193240.232081]  [<c14901b1>] ehci_work+0x641/0x850
[193240.232083]  [<c13da5bb>] ? ata_qc_complete+0x7b/0x1d0
[193240.232086]  [<c13eae50>] ? ata_sff_error_handler+0xf0/0xf0
[193240.232088]  [<c148e7fb>] ? qh_link_async+0x2b/0xb0
[193240.232090]  [<c109ca00>] ? unmask_irq+0x20/0x20
[193240.232092]  [<c14911c7>] ehci_irq+0x1c7/0x3a0
[193240.232095]  [<c105b220>] ? __wake_up+0x40/0x50
[193240.232098]  [<c12ed068>] ? __mix_pool_bytes+0x38/0x70
[193240.232100]  [<c12ee53d>] ? add_interrupt_randomness+0x13d/0x160
[193240.232102]  [<c12ee53d>] ? add_interrupt_randomness+0x13d/0x160
[193240.232104]  [<c109ca00>] ? unmask_irq+0x20/0x20
```

Any advices?

Comment: I am also having trouble with this device. iw list does not show a supported ap device. However, per the ubuntu docs (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode) if you can switch to master mode without an error "your in business". However it looks like apdhost does not work with this device. I am not if there are other options other than apdhost that may work.

Answer (score 1):

Your deprecated `iwconfig` (use `iw` instead!) output shows your interface as `wlp0s29u1u2`, but your hostapd configuration mentions `interface=wlan0`.